# Wrap content width of button instead of fixed width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a **RaisedButton** which has a child **Text** and some **Padding** inside.
When I press the button, I'm using an **AnimatedBuilder** and **Container** to resize the width of the container to show a loading indicator.

```
return Container(
  height: widget.height,
  width: lerpWidth(widget.width, minWidth, _animation.value),
)
```

Now the problem is that I don't want to use a fixed width for my container since the text can be variable from length (translations, showing numbers, ..). If my passed-in string length would be bigger then the Container would not scale with it. I also don't want my button to expand the whole width of the screen.

So basically I want to expand my button to the minimum width of the child (including padding) and use that width to animate the container to show a CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: cannot you use `AnimatedSize`?

Comment: AnimatedSize would give me the same problem as I would also need to pass an initial size. I'd like to wrap my content (like in native Android) or do I have to do some precalculation?

Comment: Basically I do not want to pass an initial width and height value. I want my button to size itself based on the content given (text) and when clicked, animate it to a circle to show an indicator. Once the loading has been completed, it should animate back to it's original value.